# Prove or disprove O-notation

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

$ 3n+2\log n ∈ O(n \cdot\log n)$

have just tried to solve this through Lima, but somehow I'm not getting anywhere right now.
Can someone please help me with this?
So my solution:

$ \lim = 3n + 3\log n/ n\cdot \log n = 3n + 2/2 =$ ???

Comment: Just insert matjax in your solution, leaving all constants as is. Is it what you want?

Comment: Your arithmetic is wrong in several ways.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $3n +2\log n \lt 3n\log n +  2n\log n = 5 n\log n$, for $n \gt 1$.

Comment: why 3nlogn+2nlogn? where did you logn?
Well, I thought you take the constant and then add n. 
But in your solution do not understand where logn comes from in 3nlogn+2nlogn?

Comment: Simply use that $n \lt n \log n$ and  $\log n \lt n \log n$ for $n \gt 1$.